# extracting the first 32 bits of ASCII integer

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, biginteger, binary-data

You have an ASCII string representing a 128-bit unsigned integer number n, i.e. 0 <= n < 2^128.

Give an algorithm to extract the most significant 32 bits of the binary representation of n and return them as the unsigned 32 bit integer they encode.

What is a fast way to do this, i.e. something better than implementing your own big number division and modulo 2 operations.
Assume a 32bit machine, i. e. you don't have 64-bit built-in types.

Examples:
For brevity, let's take 4 bit integers and extract the leading 2 bits:

2(0010) --> 0(00)
 7(0111) --> 1(01)
 8(1000) --> 2(10)
13(1101) --> 3(11)

This is NOT a homework question. Updating my algo skills for  an interview.

Comment: MSB, also the integers are in decimal format.

Comment: Why do you need the most significant 32 bits? Wouldn't it be a lot easier if you simply used the lowest 32 bits? I understand this is just an exercise for an interview, but I cannot see why this would be important.

Comment: To clarify: you mean the 32 bits of integer itself, not of it's string representation? How large the numbers can be - up to +infinity? What to consider the first 32 bits - starting from the first non-zero bit?

Comment: @RocketR Yes, the bits themeselves, given as a result in 32 bit int, i.e. the function will return a single int, which has bit representation identical to the first 32 bits.

Comment: @RocketR Let's assume the numbers are unsigned integers that can fit into 128 bits. If we don't give a fixed bit size representation the question indeed becomes unclear.

Comment: @Spasski: You say 32-bit system. Can we assume that a 32-bit by 32-bit into 64 bit multiplication is available? (x86 has this). In that case, we can easily simulate 128-bit arithmetic using four 32-bit numbers and do the carrys ourselves.

Comment: @Spasski: With the numbers being unbounded, comparing the MSBs is not always the same as comparing the numbers themselves. The most significant 32 bits of a 1024 bit value might be less than the most significant 32 bits of a 128 bit value.

Comment: @hammar: Yes we can, assume it's a x86 architecture. Could you give a bit more detail on this approach?

Comment: @starblue 10^1 is a multiple of 2^1. Does that mean we can ignore groups of 1 digit at the end of a number? Your premise is false, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a more efficient way than to simply emulate (a limited form of) 128 bit arithmetic.

Let's say we have a function `mul10add(a, b)` which calculates `10*a + b` and returns the lower 32 bits of the answer together with a carry value. If we have 64-bit arithmetic it can be implemented as (in pseudo-code):

```
(word32, word32) mul10add(word32 a, word32 b):
    word64 result = 10*a + b
    word32 carry  = result >> 32
    return (result, carry)
```

Now, we take the normal decimal-to-binary algorithm and represent the 128-bit number `n` with four 32-bit words `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` such that `n = x*2^96 + y*2^64 + z*2^32 + w`. We can then chain calls to `mul10add` together to perform the equivalent of `n = 10*n + digitToInt(decimal[i])`.

```
word32 high32bits(string decimal):
    word32 x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0

    # carry
    word32 c = 0

    for i in 0..length(decimal)-1
       (w, c) = mul10add(w, digitToInt(decimal[i]))
       (z, c) = mul10add(z, c)
       (y, c) = mul10add(y, c)
       (x, _) = mul10add(x, c)

    return x
```

We don't actually need a 64-bit architecture to implement `mul10add`, however. On x86 we have the `mul` instruction which multiplies two 32-bit numbers to get a 64-bit number with the upper 32 bits stored in `edx` and the lower ones in `eax`. There's also the `adc` instruction, which adds two numbers but includes the carry from a previous `add`. So, in pseudo-assembly:

```
(word32, word32) mul10add(word32 a, word32 b):
    word32 result, carry
    asm:
        mov a, %eax
        mul 10
        add b, %eax
        adc 0, %edx
        mov %eax, result
        mov %edx, carry
    return (result, carry)
```

Comment: This is nice solution. I am curious if it can be extended to a general case of having n bit integer as opposed to 128 bit.

Comment: @Spasski: Sure, just add more words to represent `n` and corresponding calls to `mul10add`. Or use an array plus a loop to make it work on an arbitrary amount of bits. (Though for numbers of bits that are not multiples of 32, you'll have to combine bits from the top two words).